# Attach pdf to mail with js

Tags: javascript, php, html, jspdf

I am using jspdf to generate pdf. I am using that library to generate pdf in my ionic app which generates somekind of report and the file plugin, mail plugin are used to create file and attach to email app and this is pretty cool and easy there.

But i am migrating this to web user. I can also generate the pdf in the browser and can be saved to user pc.Is there handy method that i can attach generated pdf  instantly to the form ?(I think **mailto**: cannot be used to attach the file so i want to use form to send the pdf file to server).
And last question, i can send the base64 data to php server.Is there any method that base64 can be converted to pdf in php? (i am not much familiar with the php)

Comment: The way to go is probably to build yourself a web service which you hand the pdf and then send out the mail.

Comment: Have Done? @suraj

Comment: Not yet @Crock but I have planned to do this with php as my backend.

Comment: Anyone coming to this question, just send the pdf data using form data.